# Proper usage of passive voice in the literature survey of scientific article

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, passive-voice

I want to write following sentence in the literature survey of scientific research paper in the Mathematics field.

> Author A and B proposed a convergent iterative method for computing matrix inverse.
>   Error bounds of the method **were/are** also obtained by them. Necessary and sufficient conditions for convergence **were/are** also proved.

I often got confused about using **were/are** in such sentences as above. Please clear my doubt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Authors A and B *proposed* it.  Being that *proposed* is in the past tense, you would use the past perfect "*were* obtained" rather than the present perfect "*are* obtained."

Now, that said, since you are saying "by them," thus attributing the action to someone and negating any need for the passive voice, it becomes advisable to instead say, "They also obtained the *error bounds* of the method ("error bounds" italicized due to it not being clear whether or not this term is correct)."

Comment: One small quibble: not attributing the action to someone is not the only good reason to use passive voice (although in this case, I don't know if I see any good reasons).

Comment: @Peter Shor : Yes, I agree.  The other prominent reason would be to shift focus onto the action itself rather than the doers of the action.  That purpose, however, is likewise circumvented by the verbosity "by them."  (See what I did there? ;-))

Comment: @BenjaminHarman Thank you very much for clearing my doubt. It helped me a lot. :)